# How to create a hierarchy ID

Tags: c#, hierarchy

I'd like to make a method to generate a hierarchy ID like the following

```
1.0
 1.1
   1.1.1
   1.1.2
   1.1.3

 1.2
 1.3
2.0
 2.1
```

is there and way to accomplish this ?
any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you simply need to output an existing hierarchy? Most graphs will already have a hierarchical structure, so your question is not very clear.

Comment: Some nested for loops or a recursive function paired with some kind of stop condition will fix this for you. You should elaborate your question a little bit. Mention what input you would give (level, stopcondition?) and how the output should be formatted (List<string>, space separated string, html code with links?). Will your get one value at a time or all together?

Comment: thanks for your reply
simply I'd like to generate this id for each new element 
I've an parent child relation and i need to attribute each child with parent id + the child ID 
suppose parent id is "1" so i need to generate all children to this parent on the following way
First child ID 1.1
Second child ID 1.2 
Third child ID 1.3
and all children may parents to other children, suppose the firs child also has a children so the new ids should be as follows
first child ID should be 1.1.1
second child ID should be 1.1.2
ans so on.

and the input will be the parent ID it may be 1 or 2 or 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my quick attempt.

I am assuming that instead of `1.0` and `2.0` you meant just `1` and `2`, respectively, as otherwise it would be inconsistent.

```
public class HierarchyGenerator
{
    private List<int> levels = new List<int> { 1 };

    public void DownOneLevel()
    {
        levels.Add(1);
    }

    public void UpLevels(int numLevels)
    {
        if (levels.Count < numLevels + 1)
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                "Attempt to ascend beyond the top level.");

        for (int i = 0; i < numLevels; i++)
            levels.RemoveAt(levels.Count - 1);
        MoveNext();
    }

    public void MoveNext()
    {
        levels[levels.Count - 1]++;
    }

    public string Current
    {
        get
        {
            return new string(' ', (levels.Count - 1) * 2)
                 + string.Join(".", levels.Select(l => l.ToString()));
        }
    }
}

static partial class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var hg = new HierarchyGenerator();
        Console.WriteLine(hg.Current);  // 1
        hg.DownOneLevel();
        Console.WriteLine(hg.Current);  // 1.1
        hg.DownOneLevel();
        Console.WriteLine(hg.Current);  // 1.1.1
        hg.MoveNext();
        Console.WriteLine(hg.Current);  // 1.1.2
        hg.MoveNext();
        Console.WriteLine(hg.Current);  // 1.1.3
        hg.UpLevels(1);
        Console.WriteLine(hg.Current);  // 1.2
        hg.MoveNext();
        Console.WriteLine(hg.Current);  // 1.3
        hg.UpLevels(1);
        Console.WriteLine(hg.Current);  // 2
        hg.DownOneLevel();
        Console.WriteLine(hg.Current);  // 2.1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume that your hierarchy is expressed like a tree using this class:

```
class Node {
  public Node() { Children = new Node[0]; }
  public String Name { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<Node> Children { get; set; }
}
```

You can then visit each node in the tree using this method:

```
void Visit(Node node, Stack<Int32> levels, Action<Node, String> nodeAction) {
  // Generation of hierachyId can be customized here to say use letters.
  var hierarchyId = 
    String.Join(".", levels.Reverse().Select(l => l.ToString()).ToArray());
  nodeAction(node, hierarchyId);
  var i = 1;
  foreach (var child in node.Children) {
    levels.Push(i++);
    Visit(child, levels, nodeAction);
    levels.Pop();
  }
}
```

This code will visit each node in the tree in a depth first order including the root. However, the root will have an empty `hierarchyId`. To start visiting the tree use this code:

```
Visit(
  root,
  new Stack<int>(),
  (node, hierarchyId) => Console.WriteLine(hierarchyId + ": " + node.Name)
);
```

The action will simply write the node name and generated hierarchy id to the console.

Here are some sample data:

```
var root = new Node {
  Name = "Root",
  Children = new[] {
    new Node {
      Name = "A",
      Children = new[] {
        new Node {
          Name = "AA",
          Children = new [] {
            new Node { Name = "AAA" },
            new Node { Name = "AAB" },
            new Node { Name = "AAC" }
          }
        },
        new Node { Name = "AB" },
        new Node { Name = "AC" }
      }
    },
    new Node {
      Name = "B",
      Children = new Node[] {
        new Node { Name = "BA" }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Running the code on this tree writes the following to the console:

```
: Root
1: A
1.1: AA
1.1.1: AAA
1.1.2: AAB
1.1.3: AAC
1.2: AB
1.3: AC
2: B
2.1: BA
```